# Overwrite JSON if fields match PHP

Tags: php, json, file

I'm trying to write to a json file, and want to be able to overwrite an object if certain fields match. Right now, I have code that gets whats currently in the JSON file, but that just adds the latest object to the end of it. What I need to do is that if the message fields match, then I need to replace the entry with the newer one. Know what I mean?

Thanks for the help!

**PHP:**

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.json');
$data = json_decode($file);
unset($file);//prevent memory leaks for large json.
//insert data here
$data[] = array("message" => $name, "latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon, "it" => $it);
//save the file
file_put_contents('test.json',json_encode($data));
echo json_encode($data);
unset($data);//release memory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to find the element with the matching name and update it in place.  This will not remove any existing duplicates for you, though.

```
$datum = array_filter($data, function (&$elem) use ($name, $lat, $lon, $it) {
    if ($elem['message'] === $name) {
       $elem = array('message' => $name /* snip */)
       return true;
    }
});
if (!$datum) { /* append array */ }
```

Comment: do note, that while correct, the above will loop over the entire $data array for each item you want to check.

Comment: so large amounts of data will bog this method down. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: @hexblot Now i'm getting a parse error. says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{'` on the first line with `$datum...` nothing seems wrong, but thats what i'm getting

Comment: @copilot0910 sorry, I had an extra paren in there

Comment: @ExplosionPills Now, I'm getting an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF` Heres a link to my code. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much for your help so far as well as help to come. http://pastebin.com/idCuYM3j

Comment: @copilot0910 you're missing the closing paren and semicolon for the `array_filter` function call

Comment: One more problem. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{'` Heres the link again -- http://pastebin.com/idCuYM3j The error is on the `$datum...` line

Comment: @copilot0910 if you are a developer you really need to understand what you are doing and not just copy and paste code.  You need to be able to debug these issues yourself too.  The problem is that the `);` you have added is invalid.  It needs to go after the anonymous function's closing `}` (on line 44).

Comment: These problems happen and ive been reading so many forums but couldn't find an answer that suits my need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming I understand correctly, you only need to check if two elements in your `$data` array are equal, based on the message. Easiest way to do that is use the key of the data array, and reset it afterwards. so something similar to :

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.json');
$data = json_decode($file);
unset($file);//prevent memory leaks for large json.
//insert data here
$data[$message] = array("message" => $name, "latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon, "it" => $it);

//save the file
$data = array_values($data);
file_put_contents('test.json',json_encode($data));
echo json_encode($data);
unset($data);//release memory
```

this will increase memory consumption, so you can use `md5()` for the keys instead to keep it low.

Comment: To make sure I understand, by using the `$message` as a key, I am checking if a duplicate already exists, and if so, it is being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

If you use json_decode($string, true), you will get either an associative or numeric array. This array can be manipulated with standard php array methods.

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
if(md5($data['message']) != md5($newMessage)) {
    $array['message'] = $newMessage; 
}
```

I used an md5, because i don't know how the message is structured.